# Can I cancel a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, dismiss the view and get a long press to recognize on the view underneath?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a long-press gesture recognizer on it.

In my app, I have to temporarily place another view over it, but the area where the underlying view is positioned is transparent, so the user can still see the view underneath.

I added a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the new top view.  When the user does a long-press on the view they can see (which is under the top view), I recognize it in the top view.  I cancel it (with `g.enabled = NO;`) and then I dismiss my top view.

Now, I'd like to make the view that the user meant to long-press on have its gesture recognizer fire.  Is there a way to do that?

*Update:*

Based on @matt's suggestions in comments I removed the gesture recognizer from my top view -- and this is giving me a lot more insight and control -- but I haven't gotten there yet.

I have experimented with `hitTest:withEvent:` to ignore the events in my transparent area, but so far I have not gotten that to work (have the events kick off a gesture in the underlying view).

Right now I am trying to re-route `touchesBegan:withEvent:` by having my top view send them right to its view controller to see if that would further propagate from there, but I haven't gotten that to work.

I am still debugging to figure out if the touches are being sent to the bottom view -- I'm not sure if this will eventually kick off the recognizer, which is my goal.

Comment: _Why_ did you add the gesture recognizer to the new top view? Clearly this additional gesture recognizer is simply getting in your way. Just let the back view recognize it. It can easily figure out that this is happening in the new top view and, if it is, it can respond accordingly.

Comment: I should have said the top view is in a new VC. Can I pass it through even with a new VC?

Comment: "Can I pass it through even with a new VC?" You tell me. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen automatically -- I am trying to route it there, but I haven't gotten it to kick off a gesture.  I will edit the question with where I am now.

Comment: My responder chain doesn't include the underlying view controller, perhaps because it is fully covered.  I will try to route it myself.

Comment: Okay, then you won't be able to use my solution. So you will need to _communicate_ from the child v.c. to the parent v.c. But if you've done this right, the child has a reference to the parent, so no problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help -- almost there -- will post results when I get it.

Comment: I've provided that idea as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top view is just a view, then perhaps it would be easier not to add a gesture recognizer to it at all. You could leave the gesture recognizer attached to the view behind it. Gesture recognizers operate up the view hierarchy automatically, so the gesture recognizer attached to the view behind will respond to the long press on the top view.

If the top view belongs to a custom contained view controller, and the view behind it belongs to the parent view controller, the contained view controller has a reference to the parent view controller as its `parentViewController`. So your gesture recognizer handler in the top view can send a message to the `parentViewController` which can then do whatever it would have done in its own gesture recognizer handler.

Comment: There's a little more to it, but this is very close (still working on it).  Gesture recognizers are outside the responder chain, so I need to deliver it myself -- will update when I get it working.  If you are routing touchesBegan, run `hitTest` on your parentVC's view and deliver to the view it returns.

Comment: I'm not actually suggesting that you go that far. I'm suggesting that you restore the long press gesture recognizer on the top view, handle it, and then, as you dismiss the contained view controller, call the parent and say "now _you_ handle it". You will need a method in the parent that the child can call.

Comment: In this case, the longpress handling in the bottom view is very complex and has to deal with the full lifecycle (it actually tracks movements like a pan after the hold is recognized -- so like a hold, then pan).  So I need it to start recognizing the touches itself -- there is no way to write a "handleIt" function on the parent -- it needs to start tracking (via the longpress it has) all of the touches. (but I think I've got it from here -- thanks!)

Comment: In the end, I had to just remove the view controller and make the top view  a subview that is on the top  -- then it all "just works" -- you do need to manage `hitTest:` in the top view to return NO when you want a passthrough.

Comment: Well, that was my _first_ suggestion. :) Do you want me to rewrite my answer? I could include both solutions... Or you could just write your own answer and I could remove mine. Up to you!

Comment: Revised my answer to cover both bases.